# Paste event on mat-dialog

Tags: angular, events, paste

I want my users to be able to use Ctrl-V (paste) directly after they opened a `MatDialog`, so  they can paste screenshots using the `FileUploadComponent`.

I open it as-such:

```
   this.dialog.open(FileUploadComponent, {
                width: '640px',
                height: '600px',
                panelClass: 'main-dialog',
                data: this.dialogData,
            }
        )
```

The `FileUploadComponent` is something like this:

```
<h3> {{ 'attachments.add' | translate | titlecase }}</h3>

<div *ngIf="!hasPreview" class="select" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
    <div class="container" appDnd (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
        <input type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target)"/>
        ...
</div>
```

As you can see the (paste) event is now on the `div` and only works if the uses first clicks the div.

How to add it to the entire `dialog`?

Comment: try adding the `autofocus="true"` on the div

Comment: Tried. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly listening to `document:paste` works.

```
//Explicitly add Document:paste as event to listen to!
//We need to listen to the paste event on the *document*, because there
//are no components that have focus.
@HostListener('document:paste', ['$event'])
public onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent): void {

    //Only care if there is clipboard data
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        const items: DataTransferItemList = e.clipboardData.items;
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const item: DataTransferItem = items[i];
            if (item.type.indexOf('image/') === 0) {
                let blob: File | null = item.getAsFile();
                if (blob) {
                    this.targetFileName.setValue('Screenshot.png');
                    this.stageFile(blob, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```